# Source port is a Dynamic Port

Tags: networking, port

**How do we say this source port is a dynamic port?**

*so this is the question that is given to me to analyze the network using Wireshark.
-> Observe the Source port. Notice that it is a dynamic port selected for this connection*

Comment: I would guess it means it changes each time. Not really a programming question though. [networkengineering.se] or [sf]??

Comment: The terminology is  _ephemeral_ port. IANA calls the range it set aside for that as _Dynamic and/or Private Ports_, but different OSes have different ranges for ephemeral ports than what IANA has defined.